# finding the biggest value

Tags: c, algorithm

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am not looking for code, but for a way how to solve this problem.

My input is world that looks like this:
[image: input world]

The problem is, i have to find the biggest number, **without using OWN variables I could declare myself**, and I'm **only** allowed to use `turnLeft()`, `turnRight()`, `move()`, `isLeft/Right/FrontClear()`, `getNumber()` and `putNumber()` functions to move `<` around the world.

Could you please give me a 'verbal solution' or a hint how to do such thing?

Comment: What do you mean "without using variables" ? Your input is already stored in a variable...

Comment: @MartinVerjans the input is loaded via an external library that uses functions above to manipulate the world (moving `>` around the world). I can not create any variable.

Comment: I don't see how you can write a non-trivial program without any variables.

Comment: What's the prototype for `putNumber()`? Where do you put it? What number do you put?

Comment: @pmg `putNumber(int n);` it writes a number to a current location of `<`. 0 means dot

Comment: @Quest well, there you have your variable.

Comment: again.. I can not declare my own variables.. ofc that library uses variables

Comment: @Quest When there is an api to put numbers into the maze you do have access to variables you can use. your "without using variables" is misleading.

Comment: @Swordfish What should I write instead? Feel free to edit the question if it helps

Comment: If you can get and put a number, you can carry around numbers. The world is your variable.

Comment: @Quest maybe "without using OWN variables I could declare myself"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you cannot use any variable, note that you do have available memory (`getNumber()` and `putNumber()`). For instance, you could think about leaving a mark in positions you have already been to implement some kind of flood fill.

Further, you can fill the floor with the biggest number you have seen yet. Basically, encoding your own state in the floor.

Important questions:

- Is the configuration of the maze always fixed?
- Is the range of possible numbers in the floor fixed to a reasonable range (e.g. digits `1-9`)?

Comment: The code has to be universal, you have more than one world.
yes the number is fixed to 1-9 while dot means 0

Comment: Then the question to solve is how you will stop the algorithm, i.e. how do you know you have seen all the floor.

Comment: but how will you know which one is the biggest one?

Comment: @Quest If you can only set states `0-9`, you could jump to a different part of your code when you see a bigger one; so you would know which one is the current biggest seen (i.e. have a block of code for `1`, a block for `2`, etc.). However, I do not see how you would know when to stop the algorithm if the maze is arbitrary. You need to, somehow, fill the world and be sure you do not leave anything behind.